# Is there a graph on 100 vertices, where each degree is 97?

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a graph on 100 vertices, where each degree is 97?

I believe that if each vertices is 97 degrees, 2 vertices are connected together and creates two graphs.

Is it possible to create a graph on 100 vertices, where each degree is 97?

Comment: Hint: what would be  the complement of such a graph?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. $K_{100}$ minus any Hamiltonian cycle will do.